# Chartjs rotacionar texto

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, chartjs

Gostaria de saber, tenho um texto criado com canvas no chartJS]. Como faço para rotacionar o texto, o mesmo ficando na vertical no centro da linha. Tentei com Rotate, mas desapareceu do gráfico o texto.

**EXEMPLO**

https://jsfiddle.net/esb8nh6g/

Answer (score 0):

o canvas tem os métodos translate() e rotate() que podem ajudar nesta situação:

```
ctx.translate(xaxis.getPixelForValue(undefined, index) -16, yaxis.top + 5);
ctx.rotate(-90*Math.PI/180);
ctx.fillText("ROTATE", 0, 0);
```